# Who signed this Chinese peice of art? (Characters identified: 吳氏 小平画印)

Tags: translation, traditional-characters, character-identification, seal

I am trying to understand the seals and title for this painting. I have tried importing the image of the painting in Pleco and many other seal identification websites, but still no luck. I believe it could be a painted by a very famous Chinese artist and I need to verify its authenticity. Do you know what the signature says?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

i think it's: 
`巫峡神女峰`

`壬午年`

`xx月`

Can't tell which month it is.. maybe someone else can identify it.

Comment: it seems like 夏月 to me, 夏 is elongated like 峰. It can also be 夏日 which is a common term for Summer season

Answer (score 1):

Last line:

[image]

> **小平畫**
>
> *Drawn by* 小平

Seal 1:

[image]

> **吳氏**
>
> 吳 *family/clan*

Seal 2:

[image]

> **小平画印**
>
> *Drawing seal of* 小平

---

There is no "title" of the painting as such - the theme of the painting can only be inferred from the text, which as @sylvia points out literally says:

> 巫峽神女峰壬午年丙Ｘ月
>
> *Painted at Shénnǚ peak of the [Wū Gorge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_Gorge) on the Year of [Rénwǔ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A3%AC%E5%8D%88) and month of* 丙*X*.

Comment: it seems like 夏月 to me, 夏 is elongated like 峰. It can also be 夏日 which is a common term for Summer season

Comment: @TangHo thank you, that looks reasonable.